# how do i make xul's <browser> to have its own profile?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, xpcom, xulrunner

I'm using two `<browser>`s in a `xul` that should use a different profile each. both are navigating the same site (it's a webapp) but they should handle their session individually. currently if I set a cookie in one of them, it will be available on the second `<browser>` as well. is there a way to have them totally independent?

Comment: i think what you're trying to do is called sandboxing, try searching that keyword, i dont know much about this otherwise i would help out more

Comment: I tried but I haven't had any success

Comment: Dang, its a tricky thing. Hopefully someone can help you out. Here's sandboxing http connections: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Creating_Sandboxed_HTTP_Connections

Comment: You should check out the addon Multifox, it allows multiple logins in different tabs, thats gotta be sandboxing.

Comment: i checked Multifox, apparently what it does is just override document.cookie, window.localStorage and similar ones with a custom implementation... is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe look into private tabs. I think in a private tab, everything it does is confined to within it. Unlike a private window which shares across tabs in that window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<browser>s` and networking stuff are mostly independent. That is: There is one cookie service and one HTTP "service" that uses the cookie service... Or one *profile* if you prefer that.
You cannot run two profiles in the same process...

Well, actually now there are two sets of cookies (and caches, etc. - or user state in general). The regular one and a volatile one for private browsing. If you're really only after two different `<browser>s` and not `n>=2`, then toggling one of the `<browser>s` into private browsing mode may suffice for your use case.
In general it should be possible to set `PrivateBrowsingUtils.privacyContextFromWindow(window).usePrivateBrowsing = true;`, where `window` is the `.contentWindow` of your `<browser>`. Use `Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/PrivateBrowsingUtils.jsm")` to load the utility code module in your window first ;)
It may be possible to get some *inspiration* from the great [Private Tab](https://github.com/Infocatcher/Private_Tab) add-on in this area, as this is essentially what that add-on does: Put `<browser>s` with different private browsing mode and hence user state into the same window.

*Update 1*: A private *session* is basically a regular session, separately keeping track of cookies, localstorage, caches etc, but is only kept in memory and never written to disk. As such it will go away once the application exits. Additionally, once the last private window context closes (well, the `nsIDocShell` associated with it), the [`"last-pb-context-exited"` notification will be sent](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/docshell/base/nsDocShell.cpp#768), which causes the private session to be dropped as well. If you run into problems where the private session vanishes prematurely, just keep another (hidden) private `<browser>` around somewhere.

If this does not suffice, then consider running two separate Firefox instances. The `-profile <path>` and `-no-remote` (to run sessions in parallel) switches are your friends here.

If you're only after cookies, it also would be possible to [manipulate the cookies requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Creating_Sandboxed_HTTP_Connections#Handling_cookies) originating from your `<browser>s` by [getting the `<browser>` first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Getting_the_browser_that_fires_the_http-on-modify-request_notification) if any, and then adding `Cookie` headers as appropriate. Of course, this will **not** affect other stuff the site may use such as `localstorage` or `IndexedDB`, so it might not be sufficient.

If all of the above doesn't really work for you, then I guess you're out of luck...

It might be possible to do more fancy stuff with `e10s` (multi-process Firefox) in the future, but IIRC using two profiles in one application instance is not supported or possible with it nor planned (judging from Nightly, where there is already experimental `e10s` support).

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer, really helpful! i don't actually know how private browsing works... cookies, session, local storage etc are kept as long as xulrunner is running? in this case it might work, because i'm already asking the user/admin to login each time he starts xulrunner

Comment: Amended my answer (Update 1) to address your questions.

Comment: awesome! thanks, it seems private browsing is what i was looking for